# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. code not injected

Tags: javascript, styles, code-injection

I am new developing and trying to inject this code in the console so changes things on my website but it does not work properly. The website is build on SPA and I have to login to enter. I have to inject this code in the console first to test it and if it works then in adobe target.

If i Inject only the ADD CODE part without the function it works fine. But when I turn it into a function it does not works

I get this error in the console:

> VM6228:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of
>   undefined
>       at funcionCarga (:13:78)
>       at hashHandler (:69:13)

This is my code

```
(function () {
    var funcionCarga = function () {

    var existeDOM = function () {
        return document.getElementById("region-content") <= 0;
    }
    var interval;

    //ADD CODE
    //1) Hide orange button1
    var HideButton = document.getElementsByClassName('row Botones')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';

    //1.1)Resize Whitebox
    var TABwhitebox = document.querySelector("#ventajas> div > div")
    TABwhitebox.style.minHeight = "220px";
    TABwhitebox.style.marginBottom = "80px";

    //2) grey button to orange
    var Obutton = document.getElementsByClassName("nuevo btn-secondary btn-block btn-reason");
    for (i = 0; i < Obutton.length; i++) {
    Obutton[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FF6200";
    Obutton[i].style.borderColor = "rgb(255, 98, 0)";
    Obutton[i].style.borderRadius = "8px";
    Obutton[i].style.borderStyle = "solid";
    Obutton[i].style.alignItems = "flex-start";
    Obutton[i].style.borderWidth = "0.989583px";
    Obutton[i].style.boxSizing = "0.989583px";
    Obutton[i].style.boxSizing = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    Obutton[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
    Obutton[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    Obutton[i].style.fontFamily = "INGMeBold";
    Obutton[i].style.fontSize = "19px";
    Obutton[i].style.fontStretch = "100%";
    Obutton[i].style.fontStyle = "normal";
    Obutton[i].style.fontVariantCaps = "normal";
    Obutton[i].style.fontVariantEastAsian = "normal";
    Obutton[i].style.fontVariantLigatures = "normal";
    Obutton[i].style.fontVariantNumeric = "normal";
    Obutton[i].style.fontWeight = "400";
    Obutton[i].style.height = "43.9931px";
    Obutton[i].style.letterSpacing = "normal";
    Obutton[i].style.textAlign = "center";
    Obutton[i].style.textIndent = "0px";
    Obutton[i].style.textRendering = "auto";
    Obutton[i].style.textshadow = "none";
    Obutton[i].style.textSizeAdjust = "100%";
    Obutton[i].style.textTransform = "none";
    Obutton[i].style.wordSpacing = "0px";
    Obutton[i].style.writingMode = "horizontal-tb";
    Obutton[i].style.webkitAppearance = "none";
    Obutton[i].style.webkitBorderImage = "none";}
        ;

    //Time
    var renderer = function () {
        if (existeDOM()) {
           clearInterval(interval)
           //  functionAnadir();
        }
    }
    interval = setInterval(renderer, 100) //CHANGEME: We check every X mileseconds if the page has been redered
}

function hashHandler(eventData) {
    if (eventData.newURL.includes('#loans')) { //TODO: es soportado en todos los navegadores
        console.log('im in loans');
        funcionCarga();
    }
}
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashHandler, false);

var confirmar = window.location.host.indexOf('mypage.es') >= 0;
    if (confirmar) {
    console.log("Comprobar mypage");
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashHandler, false);
 }

})();
```

I can not send the whole HTML because my work confidence policy.
There is a similar structure:

HTML BTN 1:

```
<div class="row Botones">
  <div class="boton">
    <a href="#simulator" rel="scroll">
       <div class="btn">Solicitar</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML BTN 2:

```
<button class="nuevo btn-secondary btn-block btn-reason">Elija una opción</button>
```

Is there someone that can help me?thanks

Comment: show us the HTML also

Comment: Thank you @Always Sunny. I´m new using this.

Comment: check whether you have mis-spell the class name

Comment: If i Inject only the ADD CODE part without the function it works fine. But when I turn it into a function it does not works

Comment: `document.querySelector("#ventajas> div > div")` doesn't match anything.